# Separating Velocity and Position in a Kalman Filter

Tags: matlab, covariance, kalman-filter

I have an implementation of Kalman filter for a tracking problem, with constant acceleration model. In this model:

My State Matrix is:

`x = [x, y , Vx, Vy, ax, ay]`;

My measurement Matrix is:

`Y = [x' , y', Vx', Vy']`;

I am putting the following as my Measurement Covariance matrix:

`R = [r11, r12, 0, 0 ; r21, r22, 0, 0 ; 0, 0 , r33, r34 ;0, 0, r43, r44];`

Sometimes I have my measurement Position *(x',y')* that is sometimes not so perfect. In such cases one normally puts a high Measurement Covariance on Position [r11, r12, r21, r22] to avoid a big effect on the filtered output, but it effects both Position and Velocity. The filter trusts the state more than the Measurement (Typical Update scenario)

## What my problem is:

I want to separate the Position and Velocity under certain conditions, which essentially means that I want my Position measurement (x',y') to not effect my Filter velocity. The filter should be updating the Position and Velocity Separately. The position measurement is good for the position and the velocity measurement is good for the veloctiy. But they are not good for each other (in certain cases)

## What I have already tried

I am trying to put the measurement covariance matrix on "Top Right" and "Bottom Left" (That means putting measurement covariance value on the location where there are 0s in the above R matrix) but that ultimately makes my filter more unstable.

Is there a good way to do that, or anyone faced such a problem before? Any ideas would be helpful here.

Comment: separate updates are not intended in the filter. You can take two separate filters but then you won't benefit from the other's measurements. You could run them concurrently (that is a Dual-KF) but this is usually only done if the system is not *observable*. Why is adapting the covariances not working for you? Increase the values for the position...

Comment: I'm not sure if your covariance is right. Usually one takes simply a diagonal matrix: You could go with `R=diag( [1e5 1e5 1 1 1e2 1e2]`. Why is the position measurement bad anyway? (Usually it is the acceleration -- or rather the highest derivative --, which is prone to noise...)

Comment: @max Adapting covariance doesn't work because the inverse matrix of the following $S = (H*P*H')+R$ is no longer possible after couple of cycles. As normally I am feeding the filter only with diagonal Measurement covariance and my State Matrix (P) is adapted according to that.  
Increasing the covariance value just on the position, in this case (r11, r22) says that measurement is not accurate enough and I don't have any effect on the filter state on either Velocity or Position

Comment: Answering to the question, why the measurement is bad. I have an extended object travelling in X direction. I am getting only one reference point from the object. Let's say that the object width in Y-direction is 5m. The reference point on the object changes suddenly from far end to near end. As the actual motion of the object is only in X-direction and I don't want this error in Measurement due to width of the object effect my Y-Velocity. But I want my position to move to the closest point on the object.